# running awk within a bash script

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Is there a way to run a `awk` script within `bash` script?
I have a large file (~40GB) that I want to split based on 3rd field. The third field can be either `chr1`, `chr2` ... `chr22`, `chrX` and `chrY` (total 24 types). When I run

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}$3=="chr1"{print $0}' inputfile.txt > inputfile_chr1.txt
```

It runs fine but when I try to loop it doesn't:

```
for i in {1..22} X Y; do 
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}$3=="chr${i}"{print $0}' inputfile.txt > inputfile_chr${i}.txt
done
```

I tried using single quotes for `$3` and back slash to escape `$3` but everything failed. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use your current `bash` approach. You are reading the 40GB `inputfile.txt` 24 times! Just simply parse the file once with `awk`:

```
awk '{file="inputfile_"$3".txt";print >> file;close(file)}' inputfile.txt
```

**Demo:**

```
$ ls
inputfile.txt

$ cat inputfile.txt 
1 foo chr1
2 bar chr1
3 abc chr2
4 zyz chr3
5 123 chr2

$ awk '{file="inputfile_"$3".txt";print >> file;close(file)}' inputfile.txt

$ ls
inputfile_chr1.txt  inputfile_chr2.txt  inputfile_chr3.txt  inputfile.txt

$ cat inputfile_chr1.txt 
1 foo chr1
2 bar chr1

$ cat inputfile_chr2.txt 
3 abc chr2
5 123 chr2

$ cat inputfile_chr3.txt 
4 zyz chr3
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to dig out the `i`.

```
'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}$3=="chr'${i}'"{print $0}'
```

Comment: Whilst this may be a quick fix it really isn't the fix the OP wants. There current approach would read that 40GB input file 22 times. Not to mention this isn't the way shell variables values should be pass to awk.

Comment: @djechlin: Thanks very much! so if I understood correctly: If 2 single quotes are used, it will expand variable but if I use 1 it won't, right?

Comment: @sudo_O: can you please suggest a better way? I greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or, and in my opinion better, pass i as var:

```
for i in {1..22} X Y; do 
awk -v i=$i 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}$3=="chr" i {print $0}' inputfile.txt > inputfile_chr${i}.txt
done
```